# Excute different code depending on ok,cancel and close button in confirm dailog box?

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

confirm dialog box has 3 buttons, `ok, cancel and close`. I want to perform different actions on ok and cancel button but nothing on closing the dialog box. How can I achive this using javascript?

Comment: It only really has ok or cancel (close is counted as cancel): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm, I don't see why you wouldn't perform the cancel function on closing the box as you are effectively cancelling the dialogue

Comment: Confirm dialog box has only 2 buttons: ok and cancel. e.g. confirm("Press a button!");

Comment: Ya, true but consider the situation, I want to print "OK" when pressed ok, "CANCEL" when clicked cancel and nothing on closing the dialog box, that is my requirement. It will print "CANCLE" in both cases if i pressed cancel or closed window.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, but you can use JQuery-ui Dialog instead.

This example ignore modal close action, only action on 'Ok' and 'Cancel' :

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Ok": function() { // On Ok click
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Cancel": function() { // On Cancel click
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have restriction to use javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

you can done through `jquery.ui` dialog

you also need `jquery-ui.min.js`

```
ConfirmDialog('confirm dialog');

function ConfirmDialog(message){
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
       .html('<div><h6>'+message+'?</h6></div>')
       .dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'cancel click message', 
            zIndex: 10000, 
            autoOpen: true  width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                      Yes: function () {
                            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                      No: function () {                                                               
                            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');                            
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {                                                       
                        alert('close');
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
};
```